# How to get the urldate to show up for Vancouver style using a bib file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have the following reference written in my file.bib:

```
@misc{catalan,
    type = {Online},
    title = {Catalan {Number}},
    url = {https://mathworld.wolfram.com/},
    urldate = {2022-08-21},
    author = {Weisstein, Eric W.},
}
```

And I 'initiate' my bibliography in my main.tex as follows:

```
\bibliographystyle{vancouver} 
\bibliography{file}
```

I have seen a lot of posts about this already, but I couldn't find anything that worked for me. I would like the urldate to show up in my bibliography. I found some answers that suggested writing it as
`note = "[Date Accessed 21 August, 2022]"`, but the problem with that is that my note appears in the middle of my reference, instead of after my url. So is there either a way to get urldate to work, or a way I can make sure the note gets added after the url?
Thanks!